# Why plus ones and comments are not displaying in the Google+ profile

Tags: google-plus

Google+ profile has a few menu options. Two of them are "+1s" and "Comments". These should display all the posts that I gave a +1 and and all the comments I made to other people's posts, correct? I'm asking that because plus ones and comments I did are not being displayed there. Or is it supposed to show plus ones and comments that I got from other people only?

Comment: Please be more specific about what menu options you are talking about.

Comment: When you log into Google Plus you can click on "Profile" on the menu on the left side.

It will then show your profile with a menu on the top containing the following options.

"About", "Posts", "Collections", "Photos", "Videos", "+1s", "Comments/Buzz".

I'm talking about the last two.

thanks

Comment: @abraham sorry, forget to add your name for you to be notified when I added a response to your request. thanks

Answer (score 1):

The +1's tab shows [websites you have +1'd](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1047397?hl=en), not Google+ posts. The Buzz tab is a holdover from the long gone [Google Buzz](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1698228) product. Currently there is no easy way to view the Google+ posts you have +1'd or commented on.

Comment: Thanks for the answer abraham. I didn't know it was just +1s external to G+. That's good info although an strange functionality. More obvious and usefull if it included +1s done inside G+. Interestingly enough, on that link you sent there's a link to the "Activity Log" where it is possible to see past +1s. That's part of what I wanted. I also wanted to have the count of +1s and comments I ever gave. Kind of like what you can see on twitter at the top. Any external tool you know might have that? Like hootsuite or related. thanks again